# How do I use CSS to style a dynamically generated table without changing the HTML of the table?

Tags: html, css, jsp

Currently, I'm working on a large eCommerce project. It has a lot of legacy code.

I'm tasked with using plan CSS3 to style a dynamically generated table to be mobile friendly. Here's an example of the table: 
[generated-table-image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DnnDk.png)

I would prefer to rebuild this table using SCSS and flexbox to make it mobile friendly. But, I'm not allowed to use SCSS or add to or alter the .jspf code that generates the table. Because it is being reused in 20 other places. Any changes to the .jspf code would break those other instances of the table.

Because I'm unable to alter the .jspf code I'm not sure how to set this table to stack on mobile. 
Any suggestions?

Below is the .jspf code that generates the table.

```
<!-- BEGIN ItemTable_UI.jspf -->
    <%-- text to show when the list is empty - if not set, use a generic message --%>
    <c:if test="${empty itemTableEmpty}">
        <wcst:message var="itemTableEmpty" key="ITEM_TABLE_GENERIC_EMPTY" bundle="${widgetText}"/><br/>
    </c:if>

    <div id="${widgetName}_table" class="listTable" role="grid">
        <c:if test="${isTableEditable ne 'false'}">
            <%-- table toolbar --%>
            <c:if test="${!empty toolbarType}">
                <%out.flush();%>
                <c:import url="${env_mvssiteWidgetsDir}Common/MyAccountList/ItemTableToolbar.jsp">          
                    <c:param name="storeId" value="${storeId}" />
                    <c:param name="catalogId" value="${catalogId}" />
                    <c:param name="langId" value="${langId}" />
                    <c:param name="toolbarType" value="${toolbarType}" />
                    <c:param name="orderTotal" value="${numEntries}" />
                    <c:param name="showSetCurrentOrderButton" value="${showSetCurrentOrderButton}" />
                </c:import>         
                <%out.flush();%>
            </c:if>
        </c:if>

        <%-- table header --%>
        <div id="${widgetName}_table_content" tabindex="0">
            <%-- header - pagination section --%>
            <%-- display unless explicitely set to false in data provider file --%>
            <c:if test="${headerPagination ne 'false'}">
                <c:choose>
                    <c:when test="${not empty rows}">           
                        <c:if test="${empty paginationDivClass}">
                            <c:set var="paginationDivClass" value="row footer"/>
                        </c:if>
                        <c:if test="${empty paginationDivColClass}">
                            <c:set var="paginationDivColClass" value="col12"/>
                        </c:if>
                        <div class="${paginationDivClass}">
                            <div class="${paginationDivColClass}">
                                <c:if test="${not empty fCells}">
                                    <c:forEach var="fCell" items="${fCells}">
                                        <c:out value="${fCell.cellContent}" escapeXml="false"/>
                                    </c:forEach>    
                                </c:if>

                                <c:if test="${toolbarType eq 'InputsAndButtons_OrderApprovalItems'}">
                                    <wcst:message key="MVS_SORT_BY" bundle="${widgetText}"/>
                                    <select id="sortBy" name="sortBy" > 
                                        <c:set var="sortOptionSelected" value="false"/>
                                        <option <c:if test="${param.sortBy == 'A-clientName' || WCParam.sortBy == 'A-clientName'}"><c:set var="sortOptionSelected" value="true"/>selected="selected"</c:if> value="A-clientName"><wcst:message key="MVS_SORT_BY_CLIENT_NAME_ASC" bundle="${widgetText}"/></option>
                                        <option <c:if test="${param.sortBy == 'D-clientName' || WCParam.sortBy == 'D-clientName'}"><c:set var="sortOptionSelected" value="true"/>selected="selected"</c:if> value="D-clientName"><wcst:message key="MVS_SORT_BY_CLIENT_NAME_DESC" bundle="${widgetText}"/></option>
                                        <option <c:if test="${param.sortBy == 'A-submitTime' || WCParam.sortBy == 'A-submitTime'}"><c:set var="sortOptionSelected" value="true"/>selected="selected"</c:if> value="A-submitTime"><wcst:message key="MVS_SORT_BY_ORDER_DATE_ASC" bundle="${widgetText}"/></option>
                                        <option <c:if test="${sortOptionSelected eq 'false' || WCParam.sortBy == 'D-submitTime' || param.sortBy == 'D-submitTime'}">selected="selected"</c:if> value="D-submitTime"><wcst:message key="MVS_SORT_BY_ORDER_DATE_DESC" bundle="${widgetText}"/></option>           
                                    </select>

                                    <wcst:message key="MVS_ORDER_PAGE_SIZE" bundle="${widgetText}"/>
                                    <wcst:message key="MVS_ORDERSTATUS_LIST_PAGESIZE" var="orderListPageSizes" bundle="${widgetText}"/>
                                    <select id="pageSize" name="pageSize" > 
                                        <c:forTokens items="${orderListPageSizes}" delims="," var="currentPageSize">
                                            <option value="${currentPageSize}" <c:if test="${WCParam.pageSize eq currentPageSize || param.pageSize eq currentPageSize}">selected="selected"</c:if>>${currentPageSize}</option>
                                        </c:forTokens>
                                    </select>   
                                </c:if>
                                <c:if test="${toolbarType ne 'InputsAndButtons_OrderApprovalItems'}">
                                    <div class="pageCount">
                                        <b><c:out value="${pageDisplay1}"/> </b> <c:out value="${pageDisplay2}"/>
                                    </div>
                                </c:if>

                                <c:set var="pageSize" value="${WCParam.pageSize}" scope="request"/>
                                <c:if test="${empty pageSize}" >
                                    <c:set var="pageSize" value="${param.pageSize}" scope="request"/>
                                </c:if>
                                <c:if test="${empty pageSize}" >
                                    <c:set var="pageSize" value="10" scope="request"/>
                                </c:if>
                                <c:if test="${totalPages > 1}">
                                    <div class="pageButtons">
                                        <c:set var="headerPaginationControls" value="true" />
                                        <%@include file="../../Common/PaginationControls.jspf" %>
                                        <c:remove var="headerPaginationControls" />
                                    </div>
                                </c:if>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </c:when>
                    <c:otherwise>
                        <div class="item_spacer_10px"></div>
                    </c:otherwise>
                </c:choose>
                <c:remove var="paginationDivClass" />
                <c:remove var="paginationDivColClass" />
            </c:if>

            <div class="<c:out value='${headerDivClass}'/>" role="row">

                <c:set var="hColClassValues" value="${fn:split(hColClasses, colValueSeparator)}" /> 
                <c:set var="hColTextValues" value="${fn:split(hColTexts, colValueSeparator)}"/>

                <c:forEach var="cell" items="${hCells}">
                    <c:set var="sortableAttributes" value=""/>
                    <c:if test="${(not empty cell.sortingAction) and (fn:contains(cell.cellDivClass, 'sortable')) }" >
                        <c:set var="sortableAttributes">id="${cell.cellDivId}" onclick="${cell.sortingAction}"</c:set>
                    </c:if>
                    <div class="<c:out value='${cell.cellDivClass}'/>" ${sortableAttributes} >
                        <div class="cell" role="columnheader">
                            <c:out value="${cell.cellContent}"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </c:forEach>
            </div>

            <%-- Table is considered editable by default. Only when isTableEditable is explicitly set to false, table is made read only--%>
            <%-- table rows --%>
            <c:if test="${!empty tableInputForm and isTableEditable ne 'false'}">
                <form id="<c:out value='${tableInputForm.id}'/>" action="<c:out value='${tableInputForm.action}'/>" method="post" name="<c:out value='${tableInputForm.name}'/>" onsubmit="return false;">
            </c:if>
            <c:if test="${isTableEditable ne 'false'}">
                <c:forEach var="inputAttribute" items="${tableFormHiddenInputs}" varStatus="status">
                    <c:choose>
                        <c:when test="${!empty inputAttribute.id}">
                            <input id="<c:out value='${inputAttribute.id}'/>" type="hidden" value="<c:out value='${inputAttribute.value}'/>" name="<c:out value='${inputAttribute.name}'/>">
                        </c:when>
                        <c:otherwise>
                            <input id="<c:out value='table_formInput_${status.count}'/>" type="hidden" value="<c:out value='${inputAttribute.value}'/>" name="<c:out value='${inputAttribute.name}'/>">
                        </c:otherwise>
                    </c:choose>
                </c:forEach>
            </c:if>

            <c:if test="${empty rows}">
                <c:out value="${itemTableEmpty}"/>
            </c:if>

            <c:forEach var="row" items="${rows}" varStatus="rStatus">
                <div class="<c:out value='${rowDivClass}'/>" role="row">
                    <c:forEach var="cell" items="${row}">
                        <div class="<c:out value='${cell.div1Class}'/>" role="gridcell">
                            <c:choose>
                                <c:when test="${fn:contains(cell.div1Class, 'actions') and not empty cell.actionsMap}" >
                                    <div class="cell" id="WC_<c:out value="${widgetName}"/>_TableContent_Action_<c:out value="${rStatus.count}"/>" role="menu" aria-label="<wcst:message key="ACCE_ACTION_POPUP_${widgetNameCaps}" bundle="${widgetText}"/>">
                                        <a table-toggle="<c:out value="${widgetName}"/>_actionDropdown<c:out value="${rStatus.count}"/>" tabindex="0" table-parent="listTable" role="menuitem" id="<c:out value="${widgetName}"/>_actionButton<c:out value="${rStatus.count}"/>" aria-haspopup="true" class="button_secondary actionButton" href="#">
                                            <div class="left_border"></div>
                                            <div class="button_text">
                                                <span>
                                                    <img alt="<wcst:message key="${widgetNameCaps}_ACTIONS" bundle="${widgetText}"/>" src="<c:out value='${jspStoreImgDir}'/>images/action_icon.png">                               
                                                </span>
                                            </div>                                              
                                            <div class="right_border"></div>
                                        </a>
                                        <div class="actionDropdown" table-parent="listTable" id="<c:out value="${widgetName}"/>_actionDropdown<c:out value="${rStatus.count}"/>" role="menu" aria-label="<wcst:message key="ACCE_ACTION_MENU_${widgetNameCaps}" bundle="${widgetText}"/>">
                                            <c:forEach var="action" items="${cell.actionsMap}">
                                                <c:set var="onclickAttribute">onclick="<c:out value="${action.value}"/>;return false;"</c:set>
                                                <c:set var="onkeypressAttribute">onkeypress="if(event.keyCode == 0 || event.keyCode == 13){<c:out value="${action.value}"/>;return false;}"</c:set>
                                                <c:set var="actionItemClass" value="actionItem" />
                                                <c:if test="${empty action.value }" >
                                                    <c:set var="onclickAttribute">aria-disabled='true' onClick="javascript:return false;"</c:set>
                                                    <c:set var="actionItemClass" value="actionItem inactive" />
                                                </c:if> 
                                                <div class="${actionItemClass}">
                                                    <c:if test ="${not empty actionLabelsMap}">
                                                        <c:set var="actionLabel" value="${actionLabelsMap[action.key]}"/>
                                                    </c:if>
                                                    <c:if test="${empty actionLabel }">
                                                        <c:set var="actionLabel"><wcst:message key="${widgetNameCaps}_ACTION_${fn:toUpperCase(action.key)}" bundle="${widgetText}"/></c:set>
                                                    </c:if>

                                                    <div id="WC_<c:out value="${widgetName}"/>_Action_<c:out value="${action.key}"/>_${rStatus.count}"
                                                            class="actionTitle" ${onclickAttribute} ${onkeypressAttribute} tabindex="-1" role="menuitem"
                                                            aria-label="<c:out value="${actionLabel}"/>">
                                                        <span><c:out value="${actionLabel}"/></span>
                                                        <c:remove var="actionLabel"/>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>                  
                                            </c:forEach>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </c:when>
                                <c:otherwise>
                                    <div class="<c:out value='${cell.div2Class}'/>" 
                                        <c:if test="${not empty cell.div2Id}">
                                            id="<c:out value='${cell.div2Id}'/>"
                                        </c:if>
                                    >
                                        <c:out value="${cell.cellContent}" escapeXml="false"/>
                                    </div>
                                </c:otherwise>
                            </c:choose> 
                        </div>
                    </c:forEach>
                </div>
            </c:forEach>

            <c:if test="${!empty tableInputForm and isTableEditable ne 'false'}">
                </form>
            </c:if>

            <%-- footer - pagination section --%>
            <c:choose>
                <c:when test="${not empty rows}">           
                    <c:if test="${empty paginationDivClass}">
                        <c:set var="paginationDivClass" value="row footer"/>
                    </c:if>
                    <c:if test="${empty paginationDivColClass}">
                        <c:set var="paginationDivColClass" value="col12"/>
                    </c:if>
                    <div class="${paginationDivClass}">
                        <div class="${paginationDivColClass}">
                            <c:if test="${not empty fCells}">
                                <c:forEach var="fCell" items="${fCells}">
                                    <c:out value="${fCell.cellContent}" escapeXml="false"/>
                                </c:forEach>    
                            </c:if>         

                            <c:if test="${toolbarType ne 'InputsAndButtons_OrderApprovalItems'}">
                                <div class="pageCount">
                                    <b><c:out value="${pageDisplay1}"/> </b> <c:out value="${pageDisplay2}"/>
                                </div>
                            </c:if>
                            <c:if test="${totalPages > 1}">
                                <div class="pageButtons">
                                    <%@include file="../../Common/PaginationControls.jspf" %>
                                </div>
                            </c:if>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </c:when>
                <c:otherwise>
                    <div class="item_spacer_10px"></div>
                </c:otherwise>
            </c:choose>
        </div>
    </div>  

<!-- END ItemTable_UI.jspf -->
```

EDIT: 
Thanks to everyone who made suggestions. I figured out how to make the table mobile friendly.

Here's an animated gif showing the table switching between normal and stack mode. 
[Mobile Friendly Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T3fFR.gif)

Here's the code I used to make it mobile friendly:

```
@media (max-width: 800px){

    .staff-registration .staff-container .tableHeader{
        display: none;
    }

    .staff-registration .staff-container .orgUsersColumn{
        width: 100% !important;
        display: block !important;
    }

    .staff-registration .staff-container .orgUsersColumn .cell{
        float: left;
        margin: 0 0 10px 0;
    }

    .staff-registration .staff-container .orgUsersColumn .actionDropdown{
     right: 0;
     left: 5%;
    }
}
```

Comment: It is comprised as divs. You should have be able to easily override any styles with CSS. Just make sure your code has a higher specificity.

Comment: @JeremyHarris I have been able to make small changes to the generated table. The problem is any styling I apply affects the table across 20 different instances. Which breaks those other instances of the table. I'm looking for a way to create styles per instance that do not affect other instances of the table on other pages. The main question is "How do I make the table mobile friendly?". I'm looking for code examples.

Comment: If you do not have a selector that is *specific* to this instance, then I don't think you can target only this. Alternatively, is there a way to include a separate CSS file in just the page with this table?

Comment: @JeremyHarris Thanks for your suggestions. I've tried adding a specific wrapper class in the page around the include that pulls in the generated table to differentiate different instances from each other. Unfortunately, some of the pages are themselves being dynamically generated so it is impossible to wrap the table in a class to target that specific instance. At the moment I'm trying to figure out how to target the generated table divs to make it mobile friendly. I've tried setting the rows to display:block and width: 100%; to stack them. Doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I put this simple code together, hope it helps. The main thing that you should focus on is to select the table using selectors. If not, the styles will be applied to all the tables.

HTML Code:

```css
table {
   border-collapse: collapse;
}

/*  Selecting td   */
table td, table th {
   border: 1px solid #888;
}

/*  Selecting td   */
table td:first-child, table th:first-child {
   font-weight: bold;
   font-size: large;
}

table td:nth-child(2), table th:nth-child(2) {
   font-weight: thin;
   font-size: small;
}

table th:last-child {
   color: blue;
}

table td:last-child {
   color: red;
}
```

```html
<table>
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th>Column 1</th>
         <th>Column 2</th>
         <th>Column 3</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td>Row 1</td>
         <td>Row 1</td>
         <td>Row 1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Row 2</td>
         <td>Row 2</td>
         <td>Row 2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Row 3</td>
         <td>Row 3</td>
         <td>Row 3</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to write out this code. I'll experiment with it.